# How can I get from MySql table ein matrix with a query

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I work with a mySql table that looks like bellow:

```
ID   mondend  |MondStart |TuesEnd   |TuesStrt  |wedsEnd  |wednStrt  
120| 06:00:00 | 22:00:00 |06:00:00  |22:00:00  |06:00:00    |22:00:00       
122| 06:00:00 | 22:00:00 |06:00:00  |22:00:00  |06:00:00    |22:00:00
```

Is there any possibility to get the table looks like this with a query?:

```
120| monday     |   22:00:00 |06:00:00  |   
   | tuesday    |   22:00:00 |06:00:00  |
   | tuesday    |   22:00:00 |06:00:00  |

122|monday      |   22:00:00 |06:00:00  |   
   | tuesday    |   22:00:00 |06:00:00  |
   | tuesday    |   22:00:00 |06:00:00  |
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT ID, 'monday' AS week_day, MondStart AS day_start, TuesEnd day_end
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'tuesday' AS week_day, TuesStrt AS day_start, WedEnd day_end
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
...etc...
```

If you want a table and not a query you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE final_table AS
...the select query above...
```

Comment: thanx but i ve just edited the question . i want the final table as i mentioned

Comment: well if i use ur answer ill get all Ids followed with same day, what i want under each ID the whole week